# Struggle with API and MongoDB - Connection issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-connection

I am following a tutorial and I am trying to connect my API to my DataBase on Mongodb.

I added the connection string to my code using .then and .catch in case the connection failed or succeeded.

I am not getting any message about connection from the console or in my terminal.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.8nytedk.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority',
  { useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true })
  .then(() => console.log('Connexion à MongoDB réussie !'))
  .catch(() => console.log('Connexion à MongoDB échouée !'));
```

Comment: You should wait for the connect function to finish. Eventually the message will show up according to whether it is failed or succeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you've whitelisted your IP address under ***Security > Network Access > IP Whitelist*** and then try to connect from a different IP address, Mongo will block the connection. It's a security feature to ensure only trusted IPs can connect to the database. You just need to go to the above mentioned section of the Mongo DB Atlas site and either add your current IP address to the whitelist or temporarily allow access from anywhere (i.e. `0.0.0.0/0 for all IP addresses`).

Answer (score 0):

First thing, make your IP white list on MongoDB server.

Kindly share which MongoDB platform you are using.

Next thing print error and share here,

Follow the below approach to print the error. No need to pass .then, .catch

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';


mongoose.connect("Your Connection String", (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
        return;
    }
});
```